# when create xamarin.android app has error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello When I create a Xamarin app on Android, I encounter the following errors after creating the application

> 1-failed linking file resources. 2-attribute layout_behavior (aka
> com.companyname.app2:layout_behavior) not found.

After seeing this problem, I saw the used version of Android, which was Android 11, and changed it to version 8.1.
The errors were fixed, but it showed me new errors

> Package Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.0.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.0.0.1 supports: monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)
> Package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat 1.2.0.5 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat 1.2.0.5 supports: monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)

Because the program has an error, I can not use nuget
And I guess Visual Studio builds my project with Android 11 libraries.
But I do not know how to change this
Please help me to fix the errors

Comment: This error means you need to set the TargetFramework as Android 9.0 or heigher.

Comment: If you stil want to use framework 8.0 downgrade the nuget packages to the compactible version

Answer (score 0):

This problem was not resolved and eventually I had to replace Windows and reinstall Visual Studio
And after reinstalling Visual Studio, I no longer had this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).